# Why I have "Update Layer Tree" and "Composite Layer" tasks after each requestAnimationFrame handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, webgl, devtools

I'm trying to write high-performance 60 - 140fps rendering code, but I noticed that after each **requestAnimationFrame** Chrome calls "Update Layer Tree" and "Composite Layer" tasks that summary takes more scripting time than my rendering function. I don't understand why does this happen? I don't update any css or resize elements so I don't think that my code requires some additional recalculations.

[image: dev-tools screenshot]

You can find that the same thing happens in this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: what if anything is happening on your page? Is it just a canvas? Is there other html? are you updating any of that html? (like an FPS meter or a framecount or a score or ....) Also how long are "Update Layer Tree" and "Composite Layers". I just tested on a simple page. I got 66µs for "Update Layer Tree" and 0.1ms "Composite Layers" which is basically nothing. Less then 0.6% of a 60hz frame

Comment: I html around canvas on my page. But I don't have any javascript calls between requestAnimationFrame time. I use some simple WebGL rendering inside canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I have “Update Layer Tree” and “Composite Layer” tasks after each requestAnimationFrame handler?

Beacuse the browser needs to do those tasks. "Update Layer Tree" may do nothing. If you've changed no HTML and no CSS and there are no CSS animations running the code might be a simple as

```
function UpdateLayerTree() {
  performance.start("Update Layer Tree");
  if (layerTreeNeedsUpdating) {
     ... update tree ...
  }
  performance.end();
}
```

"Composite Layers" is how your WebGL gets on the screen. The browser, when GPU accelerated, stores various parts of the webpage elements as textures. A WebGL canvas has its own texture. It then draws all those textures on to the browser window. Unless nothing has changed, you haven't changed any HTML nor CSS nor drawn to your canvas no CSS animations no video no gifs) then there will always be a "Composite Layers" step. And like above, it might be implemented as

```
function CompositeLayers() {
  performance.start("Composite Layers");
  if (needToRedrawBecauseContentChanged) {
     ... composite layers ...
  }
  performance.end();
}
```

Checking, If write code like this

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

function render(time) {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I see those same two processes exist but I also see if I affect the canvas

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

function render(time) {
  gl.clearColor(time / 100 % 1, 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

They go up which suggests they are implemented as above, checking if they have any work to do. I tested on [a fairly complicated page](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-primitives.html) though which is not updating any html but has hundreds of elements and several iframes with live code editors in them (6319 elements) and I still saw those 2 tasks as not taking all that long, under 0.40ms each.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation! Do you think if I will use a simple 2d rendering instead WebGL then "Composite Layer" task should take less time?

Comment: How long is it taking now? I don't think there will be any difference. For the most part a canvas is a canvas period. It represents an image. That image is usually a texture. How you fill out that texture is doesn't matter to the compositor. It still has to composite it.

Comment: My rendering function takes ~0.31ms. The "Update Layer Tree" takes ~0.61ms. "Composite Layers" takes ~0.41ms

Comment: I'm able to have 140fps, just wished to understand if I can reduce CPU usage with some tricks

Comment: Okay but at 140fps you've got 7ms so they're taking 1ms leaving you 6. You've you're using 0.3 so you've got 5.7 left or over 80% of your time left. But, no there is nothing you can do that I know of. You can make sure your canvas is "display:block;" and that it's the only thing on the page. And maybe set "alpha: false" though whether that's a plus or minus depends on the device. It's a minus on PowerVR (iPhone/iPad) but a plus on Intel and NVidia

Comment: IIRC even an empty doc will trigger these two events on Chrome. That's just that calling `requestAnimationFrame` forces the browser to set the document as "animated", and thus it has to perform the whole [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) steps. That's actually a specs defined behavior.

Comment: Interesting. I moved my canvas in the iFrame to have fewer elements in the DOM and have better performance results now. It's ~0.21 ms and ~0.32 ms now